# How Do I Change Which Key Is Used To Focus on An Object?

Tags: customization, shortcut

I can't find the key binding to focus on an object it is currently <kbd>NumPad .</kbd> I want to change it to mouse 4. Where is the binding?

Answer (score 2):

Open User Preferences then Input and then search for "View Selected" as shown below then assign the key you want instead of numpad

[image]